# Bulk renaming before upload

Tags: file-upload

I have documents in a file share, and need to do a bulk renaming before uploading them to SharePoint. The reason is that SharePoint doesn't accept some special characters, like &, /, etc.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: BY renaming... Do you mean removing all the unaccepted character?

Comment: Well, it could also mean replacing them, for example replacing all "/" with "-". But yes, the first objective is to get rid of the unaccepted characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell is indeed a great way to bulk rename the files.
Site which gives step-by-step instructions on how this can be done:

http://www.petestilgoe.com/2011/05/sharepoint-removing-illegal-characters-from-filenames-prior-to-bulk-uploading/

Answer (score 3):

I think Powershell would probably serve well here. You can read in the files and rename them, prior to uploading to SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I m not familiar with Powershell, where could I find more information on this read and rename option? Can the renaming be automated?

Comment: It's just another scripting language. Should be easy for you to pick up. :-) yes, you can write reusable script files.